# Trap signal in Bash Terminal of linux

Tags: linux, terminal, bash-scripting

1. What it means to trap a signal?
2. How to trap certain signal by its name or ID in bash?

This below is the trap code. How to edit it so that it traps certain trap codes like 9, 20, etc.

```
#! /bin/bash
trap '' 1 2 3 18 20
stty -echo
read -p "Key: " key_1
echo
read -p "Again: " key_2
echo
key_3=
if [ "$key_1" = "$key_2" ]
then
tput clear
until [ "$key_3" = "$key_2" ]
do
read key_3
done
else
echo "locktty: keys do not match"
1>&2
fi
stty echo
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To trap a signal, we have to write in syntax: **trap  .**

This results in that signal unable to get executed and when generated by the system or user, blocks its execution and run the command written before it.

For this,

1. Open a new terminal/shell
2. *Type* **kill** **-STOP** , (where PID is the process ID of that process. Do not add < > around the process PID).

The **SIGSTOP** signal would be sent.

Unfortunately, there is no keyboard shortcut for sending SIGSTOP signal.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There are three questions in your question, all about traps. This answer is about a signal, but there is nothing about traps. I don't think it answers any of the three questions.

Comment: now it explains